# GDAL. Interpolation with breaks

Tags: gdal, interpolation

I have a csv file `dem.csv` with data: LON, LAT, SO2(concentration) with NODATA=`NAN`. 
I need to interpolate my data from `*.csv` with breaks. 
I used [`gdal_grid`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) with the command:

```
gdal_grid -a invdist:power=2.0 -outsize 400 400 -of GTiff -ot Float64 -l dem dem.vrt dem.tiff
```

content of dem.vrt:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTLayer name="dem">
    <LayerSRS>4326.prj</LayerSRS>
    <SrcDataSource>dem.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude" z="SO2"/>
</OGRVRTLayer>
```

The output I get: [image].
What I actually want [image: this].

How can I interpolate data in GDAL with breaks (NAN)?